# How do I dual-wield the Blue Knight's Halberd and the Murakumo weapons?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I am trying to find out how to dual wield the Blue Knight's Halberd and the Murakumo weapons.  I have all of the necessary requirements and looked at dual wielding on YouTube and it says you can dual wield a slash and slash/thrust weapon? Any suggestions?

Comment: I am assuming the PC  version?

Comment: I'm playing on Xbox 360

Answer (score 2):

To dual wield, you need to use the button combination of two-handing the left hand weapon.

Typically, it is a long hold of the button that two-hands the right hand weapon.

If your stats are high enough, and you are using compatible weapons, then you will lift your left hand slightly.  Otherwise you will simply two-hand the left hand weapon.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's not possible to dual wield this two weapons.

Blue Knight's Halberd is Halberd, and Murakumo is Curved Greatsword. According to [compatibility table on this wikidot page](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/dual-wielding) it's not possible to dual wield Halberd with Curved Greatsword (no matter which one of these is in your right hand).